# Difference in Diameter calculation using Solidworks and manually

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics, solidworks, geometry

When I try to create a flat form of a archimedes screw using Solidworks it gives me a diameter different from what is calculated manually basically using a Pythagoras Theorem. Can anyone explain the reason as to what is used by any 3D Software in order to calculate the diameter and essentially what factors am I assuming when I calculate using the pythagoras theorem only.[image]

```
I tried to calculate a screw with pitch- 400mm, OD - 400mm and Id - 268mm
Using Pythagoras theorem gives me a OD - 430mm and ID - 297mm circle
whereas Solidworks gives a OD - 450mm and ID - 318mm circle.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with these jargon, 'Id, OD,  ...' could you please edited it up to a bit and please add at least a screenshot of your CAD showing us how you use smart dimension.

Comment: OD is outer diameter and ID is internal diameter...

Comment: Is the software working on the nearest "normalised" thread form?

Comment: if you could show your working with an appropriate diagram we may be able to help

Comment: i bet the software is just calculating a diffdrent thing than you think its calculating

Comment: @joojaa i suspected so, maybe center to center instead of arc to arc. That's why i asked OP to us how he/she uses smart dimension tools

Comment: I have added an image after flattening out the screw.

Comment: I think i know where the problem lies, please check the sketch (make a normal to the very first sketch and select edit sketch), then try to measure the parameters there, sometimes they change during the process and there is no logical reason behind it. If the values are different from what you initially inserted then edit them. If doesn't work then lemme know to find another solution.

Comment: I must say that the question is a bit oddly written. I mean it asks for a generic way CAD software calculates things. But the question is purely solidworks. I dont think you can blame all CAD applications for this. Anyway solidworks may be calculating the local space curvature try projecting a point on the 3D representation.

Comment: When you are using solidworks' sheet metal tools, you should specify the material as I believe it uses this information to help it generate the flat pattern, based on the deformation behaviour of the material.

Answer (score 1):

A flat helix ([helicoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid)) is a ruled surface, but it is not a developable surface. So you are going to have a flattening problem. Try using the middle fiber radius and compare the hand calc to the software and see if they aren't a lot closer.